# Js2Py doesn't understand require

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

when i use js2py in a python file that tries to run a javascript function inside a javascript file it sayys some error on Require() method inside the javascript file, it's not being able to execute this js function if this file contains a require method

i am trying to add require in javascript file but it gives error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am trying to execute a javascript function from a python function, the file that contains this javascript function has a require() method (it requires another file) when i try to call eval_js file( and add the path of this file) it says require is not defiined.